# Populating an existing entity using NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate

Using NHibernate, is it possible to fill an existing object using the results of a query, rather than returning a new entity? For example:

```
var foo = new Foo();
session.GetById(foo, id);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well... kind of... If you object is transient you can `Session.Get<Foo>(id)` another object into NH identity map and then manually copy its fields into your object. If your object is persistent (attached to a session), you can `Session.Refresh(foo)` to re-retrieve it from DB.

I guess you can try doing Session.Lock on your transient instance to reattach it to the session and then Session.Refresh to refresh it... Should work... at least in theory...