# Populating an existing entity using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Its sort of the same question as this: [Populating an existing entity using NHibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107155/populating-an-existing-entity-using-nhibernate) only in regular Hibernate and not NHibernate. Also that question was not fully answerd IMO.

Too sum up, is it possible (in hibernate) to fill/populate a new entity by a previously attached entity? Something like:

```
daoService.getEntityManager().find(Student.class, 123L); 
Student student = new Student(123) // Creating a new student

daoService.fill(student);
```

The result supposed to be that the student instance will have the exact value as the one found by the entity manager.

I can't use merge, as it returns a new instance (instead of filling the given instance) and I can't use load() if the ID belongs to an already attached entity.
I want the code to be generic to every entity, so its not practical to just set the values manually. I'd rather not use refelection in this context because of all the potential pitfalls (Lazy initialization, inheritance, get methods with no corresponding set methods and vice versa, etc.)

I'm working on a legacy system that uses both JPA entities and non entities (with JDBC) and this can solve me some major problems.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: So your object identifier is not auto-generated ?

Comment: It is auto generated. If I wasn't clear - the student with id 123 is already existing in my DB. I just want to populate a given entity with its value.

Answer (score 0):

the syntax is not completly accurate since i'm writing of the top of my head

```
Student student = new Student();

metadata = factory.getClassMetaData(Student.class);

metadata.getIdproperty();
// copy id

for(Property prop in metadata.getPropertyClosureIterator)
{
    prop.setValue(student, prop.getValue(managedStudent));
}
```